# Defining Custom Library Version in Mono

Tags: mono, version, gmcs

Does anyone how to set a custom library version, when compiling with the gmcs command? Basically, when I would run "monop -r mydll.dll" it should say Version=MyVersion(e.g.: 1.0.1.0).

Any help is welcome, 
Thanks in advance!

Henrique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, apparently 1.0.1.0 is the default dll version in Mono, or something like that. I found out a xml configuration file, with the name o the dll, where there is a parameter that you can define you're library version. So now, when a run `monop2 -r:mydll.dll`, it gives me my custom version. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand...if I run

```
monop2 -r:mydll.dll
```

the output is

```
mydll
Version=0.3.4146.43067
Culture=neutral
PublicKeyToken=null
```

and it's what you want to achieve...or not?